# How would you implement this adaptive 'fudge factor' in a scheduler?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++03

I have a scheduler, endlessly executing *n* actions. Each action is scheduled for *x* seconds into the future. When an action completes, it is re-scheduled for another *x* seconds into the future after its previously scheduled time. Every 1s, the scheduler "ticks", executing at most 25 actions which are due to fire. Actions may take a second or so to complete (though this value should be considered variable and unpredictable).

Say that *x* is 60 seconds. Due to the throttling of at most 25 actions being executed simultaneously, when *n* grows large, it is conceivable that the scheduler won't have time to execute all *n* actions within a 60 second window, and actions will be executed later and later as time goes on. This is undesirable, as it'll become true that there are actions to execute on *every single tick* and this increases load on my system. It's less important to me to keep *x* exactly constant than it is to keep load down.

So I wish to implement an adaptive "handicap", an automatically-applied fudge factor *h*, increasing it when a majority of actions are executed "late", and decreasing it (edging it back to its default of zero) when they're all seemingly and consistently on time. The scheduler would then be made to schedule actions for *x+h* seconds' time, rather than *x*.

At a high level, how would you approach this? How would you define "a majority of actions are executed 'late'" and how would you represent/detect it in C++03 code?

Better yet, is there an existing well-known approach that objectively "works" here?

Comment: high-watermarks and low-watermarks come to mind, though I'm no expert in throttling/scheduling algorithms. So I'll just leave that here

Comment: I would define "late" as starvation: as an action becomes starved, i.e., it will be executed later and later, its priority to execute should increase. Perhaps monotonically, perhaps quadratically. You could track the overall urgentness of your system by the largest priority, or some combination of priority sums.

Comment: Are the relative times between different tasks important?  Are you trying to guarantee real-time responsiveness within x+h seconds?   If a task significantly overruns it's execution time what should happen?  Generate a least common multiple of all task's (x+h) values, calculate the total execution time (including potential overruns) of all tasks across that time.  Repeat with incrementing values of h until required execution time <= cyclic repeat time. <- Table Based Scheduling

Answer (score 2):

To be clear, you are aiming to avoid sustained high load where there are tasks
every tick, rather than aiming to minimise the scheduling delay.
Correspondingly, the metric you should be looking at when considering the fudge
factor is the load, not the lateness.

If you have full knowledge of the system — the number of tasks, their
rescheduling intervals, the distribution of their execution time —
you could in principle exactly solve for a handicap value that would give you
a mean target load when busy, or would say, only exceed the target load
10% of the time when busy, or so on.

On the other hand, if this information is not available or predictable,
you will need an adaptive approach.

The general theory for this sort of thing is [control theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_theory), which can get
quite involved. Broadly though the heuristic is: if the load is less than the
threshold, and we have a positive handicap, reduce the handicap; if the load is
over the threshold, increase the handicap.

The handicap should be proportional, rather than additional: if, for example,
we knew we were consistently 10% overloaded, then we'd be right on target if we
applied a proportional delay of 10% on the scheduling of jobs. That is, we're
looking to apply a handicap *factor* *h* such that jobs are scheduled at *xh*
seconds time instead of *x*. A factor of 1 would correspond to no handicap.

When we're overloaded, but not maximally overloaded, the response then is linear
in the log: log(h) = log(load) - log(load_target). So the simplest method
would be:

```
load = get_current_load();
if (load>load_target) h = load/load_target;
else h = 1.0;
```

Unfortunately, there is a maximum measured load, and linearity breaks down
here. The linear model can be extended to incorporate the accumulated
deviation from the target load, and the rate of change of the load.
This corresponds to the [proportional-integral-derivative controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller).
As this is a noisy environment (there is variation in the action
execution times), it might be wise to shy away from the derivative bit
of this model, and stick with the proportional-integral (PI) part.
When this model is discretized, we get an expression for log(h)
that is proportional to the current (log) overload, plus a term that
captures how badly we've been doing:

```
load = get_current_load();
deviation = load > load_target ? log(load/load_target) : 0;
accum += p1 * deviation;

log_h = p2 * deviation + accum;
h = log_h < 0 ? 1.0 : exp(log_h);
```

Except, we don't have a symmetric problem: when we're below
the load target, but the accumulated error term stays high.
We could work around it by accumulating negative deviations
as well, but limiting the accumulated error to be at least
non-negative, so that a period of legitimately low load
doesn't give us a free pass for later:

```
load = get_current_load();
if (load > 0) {
    deviation = log(load/load_target);
    accum += p1 * deviation;
    if (accum < 0) accum = 0;
    if (deviation < 0) deviation = 0;
}
else {
    accum = 0;
    deviation = 0;
}

log_h = p2 * deviation + accum;
h = log_h < 0 ? 1.0 : exp(log_h);
```

The value for p2 will be somewhere (roughly) between 0.5 and 0.9,
to leave some room for the influence of the accumulated error.
A good value for p1 will be probably be around 0.3 to 0.5 times 
the reciprocal of the lag time, the number of steps it takes for a change
in h to present itself as a change in load. This can be estimated
by the mean rescheduling time of the actions.

You can play around with these parameters to get the sort of
response you'd like, or you can make a more faithful mathematical
model of your scheduling problem and then do maths to it!
The parameters themselves can also be modified adaptively over
time, based on the observed response to changes in load.

(Warning, I haven't actually tried these fragments in a mock scheduler!)

Comment: I'll need to read this more thoroughly in the morning, but I just wanted to jump in to thank you and to confirm that you have apparently parsed my problem exactly correctly.